# PHP script loads for browser but not Android App

Tags: php

I'm working on a simple geolocation tracker based on [this project](https://github.com/ToeBee/OsmAnd-Tracker) and OsmAnd. OsmAnd uses URL parameters to send geolocation data to the web service, which then writes it to a file. The URL input into OsmAnd looks like

```
http://example.com/tracker.php?key=j2R1nrQ&lat={0}&lon={1}&timestamp={2}&hdop={3}&altitude={4}&speed={5},
```

where the `{#}` is replaced by the location data by OsmAnd.

I have confirmed that OsmAnd is pinging my site with correctly formed data. If I open the link in a browser, it is correctly writing the data to the file, but when the app on my phone pings the page, it is not. PHP is run on the server, right? So why would it make a difference that an app on my phone is pinging the site vs. my browser?

Comment: Is your app really pinging the server ? If yes, log the requests on the server and look for the difference.

Comment: I found a different log that I was looking at before, and it's showing a status 406 for the app, vs status 200 when loading from the browser.

It also shows 300 bytes for the app, vs 453 bytes for the browser hits. There is also no user agent for the app.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The app was generating a 406 error on the server, which is caused by Apach  Mod_security. Disabling  Mod_security solved the issue.